# How Do I Let Users Sign-In Via Twitter without Invalidating Previous OAuth Tokens and Secrets from Previous Visits?

Tags: php, authentication, twitter, oauth

I am trying to better understand the work-flow of the Twitter Oauth implementation.  Currently, using Oauth to provide the user the ability to login to my site via Twitter, I can achieve the following:

- Authorize my application via their Twitter account
- get their oauth tokeh, oauth secret, and userid
- store their token/secret/id in a MySQL table for future calls.

The part I'm having trouble with is understanding exactly how I can go about re-verifying the user with the saved token/secret/id instead of re-authorizing that user every time they choose to visit my site.

If I'm not mistaken, every time the user visits my site, they request a new token/key which invalidates the previous token/key.  How do I allow them to log in again without the need to change these values in my table.

I understand that this could likely be class-specific, but I am looking for more of a step-by-step explanation of the process.

I can solve this easily with `$_SESSION` vars and cookies, but it seems like there should be a much simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `authenticate` API endpoint instead of `authorize`

Comment: does this mean that the user will have to `authorize` the app every time they want to login?  That's the way it's working for me when I try this.

Comment: @ServAce85: authorize asks authorization every time, authenticate - just once